# Wireshark Password Capture of MySQL Traffic

Tags: mysql, wireshark, packet-capture, password-hash

I'm in a test environment trying to use Wireshark to capture credentials being passed to MySQL.  I've done some digging and I read that the MySQL client hashes the password before sending even when passing unencrypted.  So, when I capture the packet containing the credentials, I'm expecting to see the username in the clear and the hashed password being passed, but that's not what I see.  The username is in the clear, but the password doesn't equal the hashed password from the database.  What's even weirder is the password changes in the packet, each time I log in.

WireShark Login Packet #1:

```
MAX Packet: 16777216
Charset: utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci (33)
Username: root
Password: ada5be054b6a9b44eaa0d86e33fb9442e8af7169
Client Auth Plugin: mysql_native_password
```

WireShark Login Packet #2:

```
MAX Packet: 16777216
Charset: utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci (33)
Username: root
Password: 78a85ed4ba56ae733057226fdc0a189b7672a0a7
Client Auth Plugin: mysql_native_password
```

WireShark Login Packet #3:

```
MAX Packet: 16777216
Charset: utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci (33)
Username: root
Password: f097e87cbba8f39cbaa3403dd5f7c966e3ed3969
Client Auth Plugin: mysql_native_password
```

I've looked at MySQL documentation and searched the Internet and can't seem to find anything on this.  Does anyone have any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Lets observe a wireshark dump of a mysql_native_password authentication of username "apoc" with the password "rockyou".

First we receive a MySQL Protocol Server Greeting (using MariaDB 10.3.31):

```
MySQL Protocol
    Packet Length: 111
    Packet Number: 0
    Server Greeting
        Protocol: 10
        Version: 5.5.5-10.3.31-MariaDB-1:10.3.31+maria~focal
        Thread ID: 10
        Salt: rC6%U]Tk
        Server Capabilities: 0xf7fe
        Server Language: latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci (8)
        Server Status: 0x0002
        Extended Server Capabilities: 0x81bf
        Authentication Plugin Length: 21
        Unused: 000000000000
        MariaDB Extended Server Capabilities: 0x00000007
        Salt: @;H8~5)orp]_
        Authentication Plugin: mysql_native_password
```

Our client responds with the Login Request:

```
MySQL Protocol
    Packet Length: 208
    Packet Number: 1
    Login Request
        Client Capabilities: 0xa684
        Extended Client Capabilities: 0x20ff
        MAX Packet: 16777216
        Charset: utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci (33)
        Unused: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000
        MariaDB Extended Client Capabilities: 0x00000005
        Username: apoc
        Password: e12a39bbf61a19c68413fa57fc65c7af3a86b85f
        Client Auth Plugin: mysql_native_password
        Connection Attributes
```

The way mysql_native_password is calculating the client password that is sent in the Login Request is using this formular ([documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_connection_phase_authentication_methods_native_password_authentication.html)):

```
SHA1( password ) XOR
    SHA1( "20-bytes random data from server" <concat> SHA1( SHA1( password ) ) )
```

To reconstruct the password we received in the Login Request (`e12a39bbf61a19c68413fa57fc65c7af3a86b85f`) we need the 20 bytes of random data (the salts) in the server greeting request.

The seed is made up of the two Salt parameters received in the Server Welcome request, `rC6%U]Tk` and `@;H8~5)orp]_` (20 bytes concatenated).

To calculate the client password hash the client uses this formular:

```
SHA1( "rockyou" ) XOR
    SHA1( "rC6%U]Tk@;H8~5)orp]_" <concat> SHA1( SHA1( "rockyou" ) ) )

= "e12a39bbf61a19c68413fa57fc65c7af3a86b85f"
```

You can use this python code to reconstruct the hash:

```
from binascii import hexlify
from hashlib import sha1 as sha1_

def sha1(data):
    h = sha1_()
    h.update(data)
    return h.digest()

def xor(x, y):
    return (int.from_bytes(x, 'little') ^ 
        int.from_bytes(y, 'little')).to_bytes(len(x), 'little')
    #  in numpy this is:
    # data = np.bitwise_xor(
    #     np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.uint8), np.frombuffer(y, dtype=np.uint8))
    # return data.tobytes()

password = b'rockyou'
salt = b"rC6%U]Tk"
salt += b"@;H8~5)orp]_"

hashed = xor(sha1(password), sha1(salt + sha1(sha1(password))))

print(hexlify(hashed))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert in MySQL, but typically password authorization is protected from [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), so sniffing network shouldn't allow attacker to authorize by sending exactly the same data. This is usually done with [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce): server sends unique data, so client must provide `hash(nonce + password_hash)` in order to authorize. On next connection different nonce is provided, different authorization data must be sent, so previous authorization data can't be reused.

Also note, that `hash` might be `hash of hash of hash of hash` and include [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) on one or multiple steps, so comparing sent data with known password requires knowing exact algorithm.

Comment: I can't seem to find the use of nonce in any of MySQL's documentation?

Comment: Ok, you made me googling MySQL protocol details. [This article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-mysql-internals/0596009577/ch04s04.html) sheds some light on authentication. Server sends random seed string to client in greeting packet, so client builds authentication data by scrambling password with seed.

Comment: @nnovich-OK, FYI, The link of the article you have shared is not hitting a 404 Not Found